# jenkins execute remote ssh running with "pts ?" ?

Tags: linux, ssh, process, jenkins

I am trying to deploy an Spring boot application(`WAR`) via Jenkins-publish over ssh.

After transfer the war file, I execute a `sh` file to run `java -jar a.war`.

And It works fine but when I `ps -ef`, it is running with `pts ?`.

This is from my console :

```
[ice@111.111.111.111 ice]$ ps -ef | grep java
ice       46338      1 42 18:02 ?        00:01:40 java -jar /home/ice/a.war -Dspring.profiles.active=ice
```

Right next time field is `pts` field. Is it ok to let it be?
Or How can I assign a pts to a process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` means the process is running without a terminal attached to it. If the program is supposed to be a daemon process, it's fine to run without a pseudo-terminal (pts). It just means you won't be able to interact with the process interactively using a terminal, which is kind of the definition of a daemon process.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried that `?` process turn into a zombie process.

Comment: That is what the 3rd column takes care of. A zombie process is a process that has exited, but the exit status hasn't been read by the parent process. PID 1 (init or systemd on most systems), checks all it's child processes periodically so that doesn't happen.